# Intellij - RestService WAR works when deployed locally, but 404 on remote server

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404, war

Just converted from Eclipse to Intellij, not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here:

When I deploy my war file locally on an instance of Tomcat created within the IDE, I can hit all services/endpoints. As soon as I take the generated WAR from my target folder and drop it on the webapps folder on a remote server, it stops working. I have exported several eclipse WARs to this very server and I can still access all of those applications. Is there some configuration that I'm missing when it comes to building Artifacts?

Not sure how much it will help, but:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
 see implementation details 
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet- 
 class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.valassis.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DalimRestService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.valassis.common</groupId>
<artifactId>DalimRestService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DalimRestService Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<build>
    <finalName>DalimRestService</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>1.19.4</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
</properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you checked server's logs? Also what URL do you use when accessing endpoints deployed to Tomcat?

Comment: The most recent logs have said that it deployed my application. It also shows me reaching for that resource and returning a 404.

The URL I'm using is {servername}:{port}/DalimRestService/json/product/hhs/upsert/20180501/test

The URL has worked in the past if I deploy from Eclipse.

Comment: Try this URL {servername}:{port}/DalimRestService/DalimRestService/json/product/hhs/upsert/20180501/test. One `DalimRestService` is because the name of your war and Tomcat by default deploys war on context with the name of the war. Second `DalimRestService` is because servlet mapping in your web.xml

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thank you!! I'm guessing, if I change the URL pattern to /*, then my original URL will function correctly?

Comment: The thing is that when you deploy from Eclipse it deploys to root context and than you have `DalimRestService` in web.xml. So you just need to keep in mind that Eclipse and Tomcat deploy to different contexts and then you have to append mapping from web.xml